# Quicksort problems (C++)

Tags: c++, quicksort

Use QUICKSORT, sort the integer array contains even number  in ascending order and uneven number in descending order.

ex: input int a[8]={4,6,1,2,5,3,8,7}
=>output is {2,4,6,8,7,5,3,1}.

---

I think the QSort function will give me look like this B={4,6,2,8,1,3,7,5} and i'll split B array to two array is C and D.

---

C array contains even number {4,6,2,8} and i'll use QuickSort to sort C array like this {2,4,6,8}

---

D array contains uven number {5,3,1,7} and i'll use QuickSort to sort D array like this {7,5,3,1}
After that i'll plus C and D. Finally my expected result is {2,4,6,8,7,5,3,1}
and this is my code :(! Thanks alot!

```
    void Input(int a[], int n)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<n;i++)
        {
            cout<<"a["<<i<<"]: ";
                cin>>a[i];
        }
    }
    void Display(int a[],int n)
    {
        for(int i = 0;i < n; i++)
        {
            cout<<a[i]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    void Swap(int &a, int &b)
    {
        int temp = a;
        a=b;
        b=temp;
    }
    void QuickSort(int a[],int Left ,int Right)
    {
        int i, j, x;
        x = a[(Left + Right)/2];
        i = Left;j = Right;
        do
        {
            while( a[i]<x) i++;
            while(a[j]>x) j--;
            if(i<=j)
            {
                Swap(a[i],a[j]);
                    i++; j--;
            }
        }while (i<=j);
        if(i<Right) QuickSort(a,i,Right);
        if(Left<j) QuickSort(a,Left,j);

    }
   //after sort the array with function QuickSort, i was suggested to use 1 more       QuickSort 
   // to move evennumber to the top of the array
    void QSort(int a[],int Left,int Right)
    {
        int i, j, x;
        x = a[(Left + Right)/2];
        i = Left;j = Right;

        {
            while(a[i]%2==0 && a[i]<x ) i++;
            while(a[j]%2==1 && a[j]>x) j--;
            if(i<=j)
            {
                Swap(a[i],a[j]);
                    i++; j--;
            }
        }while (i<=j);
        for (i = 0; i<r;i++)
        {

        }
        if(i<Right) QSort(a,i,Right);
        if(Left<j) QSort(a,Left,j);
    }


    int main()
    {
          //n is numbers of integer array
        int a[Max],n;
            cout<<"Insert numbers of array: ";
            cin>>n;
            Input(a,n);
            cout<<"Array:\n";
            Display(a,n);
            cout<<endl;

            cout<<"Array after arrange: \n";
            QuickSort(a,0,n-1);
            Display(a,n);
            cout<<endl;

            cout<<"move even number to the top:\n";
            QSort(a,0,n-1);
            Display(a,n);

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code? Is it crashing? Producing unexpected output?

Comment: For the love of mother and child use reasonable names for you variables!!

Comment: OK, first things first.  Welcome to Stackoverflow.  Homework questions get the homework tag.  Don't add things like "plzz" to your question's title.  It helps to narrow down specifically what problem you're having, dumping a big block of code on us isn't polite.  You misspelled 'integer'.  You should put spaces between your operators.  while statements go before the code block (except for do while loops).  Did I miss anything

Comment: Does the problem definitely require you to write your own quicksort, rather than just calling `qsort` with a comparison function? Because it's not obvious from your post.

Comment: @Wug: ok sorry! i'll fix my mistake in next topic :P.

Comment: @GWW: the code give unexpected output, sir! Might you show me the way to solve it? i'm stuck @_@

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the numbers 1 to 10 should be sorted as `{2,4,6,8,10,9,7,5,3,1}`?

Without looking at your code, I can tell you that you don't need two quicksort functions.

Just let even numbers compare less than odd numbers. Numbers of the same parity compare as specified.

Comment: Okay thanks! might you show me the way to solve it? i just edited my topic. My teacher said i must use Quicksort so that i can't use anotherway :(

Comment: I could, but I won't. :-) Just change the lines `while(a[i]<x) i++;`, `while(a[j]>x) j--;` and `if(i<=j)` appropriately.

Comment: @jahhaj: oh thanks! if just use one quicksort function, i can solve it ^^~! Thanks alot